# What Excel formula can I use to total column H in column L until it caps at 172 showing the amount it used to fix the deficit in last cell?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-365

Column H to total down column L, using the next cell where it comes across a deficit, and populating what amount it used to make up for the deficit in the last cell

[image]

I tried this:

```
=MIN(SUM($H$2:H2), 172)
```

but it does not use the next column to fix deficit.

I'd like it to look like this after the formula has been typed in

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(SUM($H$2:H2)-172<0,SUM($H$2:H2),IF((172-SUM($H$2:H2)+H1)>=0,ABS(172-SUM($H$2:H2)),""))
```

Keep in mind that `H1` is used so it shouldn't be numeric.

Result:

[image]

Comment: is there a way to edit this formula that if column K says "No" skip to next cell in column L and start calculating over again using the previous cells amount?  So instead of it saying 16 for L3, it would be blank and L4 would be 16

=IF(SUM($H$2:H2)-172<0,SUM($H$2:H2),IF((172-SUM($H$2:H2)+H1)>=0,ABS(172-SUM($H$2:H2)),""))

Comment: Something like this? =IF(SUMIF($K$2:K2,"Yes",$H$2:H2)-172<0,SUMIF($K$2:K2,"Yes",$H$2:H2),IF((172-SUMIF($K$2:K2,"Yes",$H$2:H2)+IF(K2="Yes",H1,0))>=0,ABS(172-SUMIF($K$2:K2,"Yes",$H$2:H2)),""))